# Checkbox that reloads page and updates url param

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I need to have a checkbox on the page that when pressed updates a url param to reflect its current state (?checked=true/false).

I'm not quite sure how to start with this, a form would require a submission button as well which I cant have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using link_to and unicode ticked and unticked chars in my view

```
- if params[:in_stock] && params[:in_stock] == 'true'
  li = link_to "☑ In stock", search_path(in_stock:false)
- else
  li = link_to "☐ In stock", search_path(in_stock:true)
```